# How to change the default editor of gcloud command?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

When I run this command

`gcloud compute url-maps edit URL`

it brings up `nano` as the default editor on my macos macbookpro

[image]

How can I change this behaviors?

I checked the documentation of [`gcloud config` command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set) but it does not have anything related to editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `EDITOR` environment variable to whatever you'd like.